# Button in bootstrap popover loses attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap popover for my django website that opens when a button is clicked. Inside this popover is another button. I am currently doing this by putting HTML in the 'data-content' of the popover, seen below:

```
<a tabindex="0" id="{{prod.title}}" value="{{prod.id}}" type="button" 
class="btn btn-secondary btn-light mt-3 mb-0" 
data-toggle="popover"data-trigger="focus" data-html="true" data-content="

<div class='btn-group-vertical'>
<a type='button' data-show-value='{{prod.id}}' id='{{prod.id}}'
 class='btn btn-secondary btn-pop wish'>Add to Wishlist</a>
</div>"

>More Options</a>
```

I need to get the 'data-show-value' in jQuery, and I am currently using the following which triggers when this button is clicked:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.wish', function () {

        var thisButton = $(this)[0]
        console.log(thisButton);
        var prodID = $(this).data("show-value");
}
```

However, all this does is return 'undefined'.

I used console.log(thisButton) to see what the button code is displaying as, and it is this:

```
<a id=10 class='btn btn-secondary btn-pop wish'>Add to Wishlist</a>
```

This explains why the 'data-show-value' is returning as undefined, as the attribute itself is not rendering on the web page.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

`.wish` is a class and there may be a lot of elements that has this class you need to specify an id instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '.wish', function () {
        var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(thisId); //check if this is the id of the element you want to trigger
        var prodID = $('#'+thisId).data("show-value");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it prodID still stores undefined once I tried this

Comment: What does this `console.log(thisId);` returns?

Comment: That returns the correct ID, but when I console.log(var prodID = $('#'+thisId)) it returns the tag with only the ID and class attributes, no data attributes at all.

Comment: Can use the id attribute to extract the product id?

Comment: In the end I extracted the HTML tag out of the attribute into the document itself and referred to it by ID. Seems to have fixed the problem